# Top screen iAd in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, iad

I just finished my game in Objective-C with the Sprite Kit framework and now I want to put an iAd banner on the top of the screen but I actually have it at the bottom and I don't know how to set it on top.

I use this code in the -viewDidLoad method in the ViewController.m but it appears at the bottom

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
```

I would thank if someone please can help me how to position the banner on the top of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your banner view like this and add it to the view

```
ADBannerView *bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc]initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
```

The default position is on the top